# sed : replace 1 word without repeating the rest of the sentence

Tags: sed

I have the following pattern :

```
foo bar
```

with `foo` being always the same, but `bar` can change. I have an hash table that, for each value of `bar`, has a new one. What I do now is:

```
sed -i 's/foo bar/foo new_value/g' file
```

I am pretty sure there is a way to avoid repeating the `foo` in the replacement string. Does `sed` provide something like this ? Like

```
sed -i 's/foo @@bar@@/new_value/g' file
```

`@@string@@` being the value that has to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed -i 's/\(foo \)bar/\1new_value/g' file`

The `\( \)`sequence "captures" the text which then can be placed in the replacement string as `\1`. This can be done multiple times, the digit in `\1` indicates which captured text to use. Captured text is counted in order of `\(` order.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it works for you :-)

Comment: I will as soon as I can (10 minute delay).